# Access Report: Wrap Text Not Working

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a report with unbound textbox's in them. I populate these fields `onLoad`.

The problem, though, is that the if the text is too long, it will not wrap.  I have set `Can Grow = Yes` but this does not seem to work.

Is it due to the fact I am adding the string to the field `OnLoad`? If so, how can I overcome this and force the text to wrap? I would want the width to remain constant, but the height to grow.

Comment: is it longer than 255chars? maybe the datatype problem

Comment: No, its not that long.  It's just longer that the width of the text box.  But, If I set the control source to ="some really long string" it wraps just fine.  It seems to be an issue of changing the value during OnLoad

Comment: odd, if I do this in my VBA: .ControlSource = "='" & myLongString & "'" it wraps the text.  But, it causes other issues.

Comment: Interesting question. Setting the `textbox.Value` in `Report_Load` wraps the textbox for me (Access 2010), but only in Print Preview, not in Report View.

Comment: Where are the unbound text boxes? Are they in the detail pane? Have you tried moving your code to other events ?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out... I right clicked the text box and selected Size > To Fit...

I had the box big enough to accommodate a second line. It wouldn't ever word wrap until I made the change above. Can Grow and Can Shrink did nothing, but I left them selected.

Answer (score 0):

I open report from code in design mode, make changes to control source of the text fields, save and close report and lastly open it in preview mode. The only way I get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I've been running into the same issue and haven't been able to figure out a solution until now.

One of the fields in print preview was getting cut off for me and despite my best efforts to make sure all the formatting settings were correct (i.e. Can Grow/Shrink: On) for both the detail section and the specific field. Again, this issue only happened in print preview, which meant the reports that were getting printed had the text cut off.

**Solution:**
I ended up realizing that all of the other text fields were set to Plain Text and the text field giving me the issue was set to Rich Text. I changed it to Plain Text and *voila*! It displayed everything without any issues.

My guess is that if you're having this issue, make sure all of the fields are set to the same property (Rich Text/Plain Text). Not sure why Access has trouble with this but I hope this solution helps someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to this huge problem is listed below.

1. Convert the property of the textbox from plain text to rich text.
2. Set the text align property to distribute.
3. Enable can shrink and can grow property of the text box. (Yes)

Done.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot trial-and-error, the solution seems to be that the text box that you want to scroll must have enough height to show two vertical lines. A textbox that is only one line high will not scroll. (You must also have Can Grow set to 'Yes' for both the textbox and the detail section.)

Answer (score -1):

You also have to have the CAN GROW of the section that the text box is in set to YES as well as the text box.